# Bash - while read > script stop after first line

Tags: bash

I read before few post with similar title but i can not figure out where is my problem.
My bash script stop every time after first line.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

UUIDFILE=./list

cat $UUIDFILE | while read TITLE
do
        ffmpeg -i ./$TITLE -acodec mp3 -vcodec copy ./$TITLE.mp4
        for file in ./*mkv.mp4; do mv "${file}" "${file//\.mkv/}"; done
        rm -rf ./$TITLE
done
```

1: Read list of movies form file "list", for example:

Movie.1.2019.mkv

Movie.2.2019.mkv

Movie.3.2018.mkv

2: Convert Movie.1.2019.mkv to mp4

3: Change name

4: Delete mkv movie

5: Again convert another movie from "list" - Movie.2.2019.mkv - Here i have problem because script stop after rm -rf

Sorry for noob question.
Best regards.

Comment: Put `</dev/null` on your `ffmpeg` line. Justaminute, and I'll find a duplicate to close it with... (This question is also [BashFAQ #89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)).

Comment: BTW, also consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. You've got some missing quotes at a minimum (`"$file"` and `"${file}"` are the exact same thing, but `./$TITLE` and `"./$TITLE"` have important differences -- the former won't work when filenames contain spaces).

Comment: ...similarly, you should use the `-r` argument in your `while read` loop so it doesn't silently make backslashes in your filenames disappear. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a full writeup around best practices for using `while read`.